# PrepareAppBundle Task Failed Unexpectedly - Xamarin Forms, VS 2022 17.1.3

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022

Re-building (Debug) my Xamarin Forms iOS project after upgarding to VS Community 17.1.3
Having iPhone attached via USB

**Receiving error:**
The "PrepareAppBundle" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
File name: 'Xamarin.iOS.Windows.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Tasks.PrepareAppBundle.Execute()

**VS Info:**
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.1.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.3+32328.378
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09022

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA164
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

.NET Core Debugging with WSL   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.1.358.51495
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.1.358.51495
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01f
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.21344.1
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

DeployToGae Extension   1.0
DeployToGae Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.6 (master@34d6af2)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   17.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.161+abc97ecc7d.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.2
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.1.10 (65f98f5)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Python - Profiling support   17.0.21344.1
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.21344.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2206201+62a2c1d6162f828801565a7ca26d9d48b810a05b
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62203.25080
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SyncfusionXamarinMenu Extension   1.0
SyncfusionXamarinMenu Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.1229.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01f
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)   17.0.32113.165
Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.21610.4+07b5673e4f2fa7630e78abe37f16b372353a7242
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Visual Studio Tools for Unity   17.1.0.0
Visual Studio Tools for Unity

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Foo   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Xamarin   17.1.0.324 (d17-1@590ddb7)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.1.0.87 (remotes/origin/main@d50fb5635)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.1.8 (590388a)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   12.2.0.4 (d17-1/19b97b7)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
Mono: a5d1934
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-1@7ac33610
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.37.1@0893b3b
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-1@db125a7

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   15.8.0.2 (79ddd0840)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: Hi , I would suggest you downgrade the visual studio , you can find the installer of earlier version here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#fixed-version-bootstrappers .

Comment: Does anyone know which earlier version works for iOS development?